# Trying to give a custom metadata but still it is using the default base metadata mentioned in class Common

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, nft, fa2

Hello I am using the template Fa2NFT library. When we add the compilation target we need to give it a metadata parameter. I am trying to give it a custom metadata but still it is using the default base metadata mentioned in class Common . Could you please point me out the difference of between metadata and metadata_common and how should I set the contract metadata?

Q from Slack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor of `Fa2Nft`, it takes both `metadata` and `metadata_base` arguments

```
def __init__(
    self, metadata, token_metadata=[], ledger={}, policy=None, metadata_base=None
):
    ledger, token_metadata = self.initial_mint(token_metadata, ledger)
    self.init(
        ledger=sp.big_map(ledger, tkey=sp.TNat, tvalue=sp.TAddress),
        metadata=sp.set_type_expr(metadata, sp.TBigMap(sp.TString, sp.TBytes)),
        last_token_id=sp.nat(len(token_metadata)),
    )
    Common.__init__(
        self,
        policy=policy,
        metadata_base=metadata_base,
        token_metadata=token_metadata,
    )
```

Both `metadata` and `metadata_base` have different purposes. When you pass your custom metadata in `metadata_base`, the IDE will create a JSON for you including all the off-chain views and other information. Then, you need to upload this JSON file somewhere and refer to it in the `metadata` field.

As it is explained in [this documentation here](https://smartpy.dev/docs/guides/metadata/contract_metadata#generate-the-json-file-in-smartpy)

> The command to generate the json file is:
> self.init_metadata(, <metadata_base>).
>
> It generates a file with the name .
>
> The content can be seen:
>
> - in the WebIde in the metadata tab of the contract
> - in the files generated by the CLI.

This command is internally called on `metadata_base` if you pass it. And, it will generate a JSON for you.

> The JSON file has to be uploaded somewhere outside the blockchain.
>
> There are two main solutions:
>
> - uploading the file on IPFS.
> - uploading it on a regular server/service that exposes the file through HTTPS.

[image]

After uploading, you'll need to pass that URI as a `metadata` argument.

```
import smartpy as sp
FA2 = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://smartpy.io/templates/fa2_lib.py")

your_custom_metadata = {
    "name": "Simplest NFT",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "An example metadata_base",
    "interfaces": ["TZIP-012", "TZIP-016"],
    "authors": ["SmartPy <https://smartpy.io/#contact>"],
    "homepage": "https://smartpy.io/ide?template=FA2.py",
    "source": {
        "tools": ["SmartPy"],
        "location": "https://gitlab.com/SmartPy/smartpy/-/raw/master/python/templates/FA2.py",
    },
    "permissions": {"receiver": "owner-no-hook", "sender": "owner-no-hook"},
}

sp.add_compilation_target(
    'Simplest NFT Compiled',
    FA2.Fa2Nft(
        metadata = sp.utils.metadata_of_url("YOUR_JSON_FILE_URI"),
        metadata_base = your_custom_metadata
    )
)
```